# ASP.NET and 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: asp.net, firefox, cookies, bad-request

Sometimes I get 400 Bad Request error for different websites written on ASP.NET.

The only solution I know is to clean up cookies for that site. Seems like that the cause of problem is _utmz and _utma cookies, which belong to Google Analytics. The problem is occurs in common cases in Mozilla FireFox, sometimes on Ghrome and Safari and never in IE. This error occurs accidentally.

What I found:

> From Stefan on the ASP.Net team:
>   http://forums.asp.net/p/1431148/3221542.aspx
>
> In current versions of ASP.NET Urls
>   containing characters like the colon
>   character will be rejected as a
>   potential security threat. The
>   historical reason for this is that the
>   underlying NTFS file system supports
>   alternate resource streams that can be
>   accessed with names like
>   "yourfile.txt:hiddendata.txt".
>   Blocking the colon character from Urls
>   prevents poorly written applications
>   from accidentally working with
>   alternate resource streams.
>
> There is also a limitation in current
>   versions of ASP.NET that incoming Urls
>   need to map to the NTFS file system
>   for purposes of determining managed
>   configuration data.
>
> In ASP.NET 4 these limitations can be
>   optionally removed. However these
>   changes are in the Beta 2 version of
>   ASP.NET 4 - they are not in Beta 1. We
>   tried out the Url listed earlier in
>   this forum post and confirmed that
>   with our internal builds of ASP.NET 4
>   you can use that style of Url and
>   process it without any 400 error.

Is is a problem with ASP.NET runtime, cookie managment process of FireFox or Google Analytics code? What problem solutions do you know?

Comment: Maybe is just too big all the cookies in size, and is not only the _utmz and _utma. Check the full size of all your cookies and try to keep them small each one and all together.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the way that firefox handles special characters in cookies. It doesn't have anything to do with asp.net, you will have the error whatever language you are using.

The issue seems to occur most often with Google Analytics campaign sources. You should simply try to keep the values in these to alpha characters.

I have personally had to fix issues where people used an apostrophe and an mDash in their query strings. As a result I tell people to just avoid hyphens and apostrophes all together. If you aren't the one including them, you can't be sure they didn't copy a special character the browser can't handle.

[This forum](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/discuss-tracking-and-implementation-issues/vT3yDFGkY68) has a suggestion for clearing the bad cookies on the 400 page so that they can access the site properly.

There is already [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206508/firefox-bad-request-caused-by-corrupt-google-tracking-cookie) with the same problem on stackoverflow.

You need to make sure that you are not including any special characters before you set the campaign sources etc. Sources that are created dynamically through CMS newsletters etc. can include bad characters if they are not formatted aggressively. We have had trouble with people pasting MSOffice characters into titles and links which break cookies and stop the page from being served.

There is no solution to the problem other than making sure that you aren't sending bad data to GA and causing cookies to be corrupted.